# Compare 2 lists and provide new list with updated quanities

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 2 lists

**grpoList**

[image]

This shows open Goods receipts. As can be seen, there are 2 open GRs for item 2010101000003 with quantities 1 and 6.

There is another Excel that has a list for invoices to be created named assembly

**assembly**

[image]

What is needed is that the oldest GRs should be closed after their quantities are exhausted. That is why I need a new list to pass to some SAP API to close them.

I need a list that looks like this.

[image]

This splits 2010101000003 as the DocEntry 19 has 1 quantity that should be closed. The other piece out of the 2 needed will come from DocEntry 21 leaving a balance of 5 in that one.

Currently I am using this code:

```
 var data = grpoList.Join(assembly,
                                x => x.ItemCode,
                                y => y.ItemCode,
                                (x, y) => new
                                {
                                    DocEntry = x.DocEntry,
                                    LineNum = x.LineNum,
                                    CarCode = x.CardCode,
                                    ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
                                    Quantity = y.Quantity - x.OpenQty,
                                    DocDate = x.DocDate,
                                    Price = y.Total
                                }).ToList();
```

However the above returns the below which is wrong. The quantities are 1, -4, -2 instead of 1, 1, 4.

How do I get the desired result.

NB. If there was a DocEntry 22 for item 2010101000003 that had 2 quantity and an invoice needing 8 of the same item, resulting list should have 4 rows of quantities 1, 6, 1, 4.

[image]

Comment: i can't figure out, how you calculate the expected quantity?

Comment: grpoList is ordered by DocEntry. These are goods receipts. The assembly list is what is needed. The oldest goods must go first. If 2 are needed, look at the oldest grpo. If oldest has only one quantity. then include that and look for the next quantity in the next grpo. That is why you will now have 2 lines of 1 and 1.

Comment: if you group by ``DocEntry`` and `ItemCode` in GR, this will give : ``7 : 2010101000003`` and ``6 : 2010101000004``,  and join it with assembly by comparing quantities, if ``Quantity  > OpenQty`` take `Quantity - OpenQty` else take `Quantity `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will get your answer. The key is to get a running total as you pick off your receipt items to fill your invoices.

```
void Main()
{
    var receipts = GetReceipts();
    var invoices = GetInvoices();

    var orderTotals = invoices
        .Select(i => new Total { ItemCode = i.ItemCode, Quantity = i.Quantity})
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ItemCode);

    var totals = receipts   
        .Join(invoices, r => r.ItemCode, i => i.ItemCode, (r, i) => new { Receipt = r, Invoice = i })
        .Select(r => new Shipment 
        { 
            DocEntry = r.Receipt.DocEntry, 
            LineNum = r.Receipt.LineNum,
            CardCode = r.Receipt.CardCode,
            ItemCode = r.Invoice.ItemCode,
            Quantity = GetToShipFromReceipt(orderTotals, r.Invoice.ItemCode, r.Receipt.OpenQty),
            DocDate = r.Receipt.DocDate,
            Price = r.Invoice.Price
        })
        .Where(x => x.Quantity > 0)
        .OrderBy(r => r.ItemCode).ThenBy(r => r.DocEntry)
        .ToList();

    totals.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.DocEntry} {x.LineNum} {x.ItemCode} {x.Quantity} {x.DocDate} {x.Price}"));


}

public int GetToShipFromReceipt(Dictionary<string, Total> orderTotals, string itemCode, int available)
{
    var remaining = available - orderTotals[itemCode].Quantity;

    if (remaining < 0)
    {
        orderTotals[itemCode].Quantity -= available;
        return available;
    }
    var quantity = orderTotals[itemCode].Quantity;
    orderTotals[itemCode].Quantity = 0;
    return quantity;
}

public class Total 
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Shipment
{
    public int DocEntry { get; set; }
    public int LineNum { get; set; }
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Receipt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DocEntry { get; set; }
    public int LineNum { get; set; }
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int OpenQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Receipt> GetReceipts()
{
    return new []
    {
        new Receipt
        {
            Id = 1, 
            DocEntry = 15,
            LineNum = 0,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2060601000127",
            OpenQty = 1,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 24)
        },
        new Receipt
        {
            Id = 2,
            DocEntry = 16,
            LineNum = 0,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2060601000127",
            OpenQty = 2,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 24)
        },
        new Receipt
        {
            Id = 3,
            DocEntry = 19,
            LineNum = 0,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2010101000003",
            OpenQty = 1,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 25)
        },
        new Receipt
        {
            Id = 4,
            DocEntry = 21,
            LineNum = 0,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2010101000003",
            OpenQty = 6,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 27)
        },
        new Receipt
        {
            Id = 5,
            DocEntry = 21,
            LineNum = 1,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2010101000004",
            OpenQty = 6,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 27)
        },
        new Receipt
        {   
            Id = 6,
            DocEntry = 21,
            LineNum = 2,
            CardCode = "S0001",
            ItemCode = "2010101000005",
            OpenQty = 6,
            DocDate = new DateTime(2020, 4, 27)
        }
    };
}

public IEnumerable<Invoice> GetInvoices()
{
    return new []
    {
        new Invoice
        {
            ItemCode = "2010101000003",
            ItemDescription = "Cambridge English IETLS 2 with Answers.",
            Quantity = 2,
            Price = 20
        },
        new Invoice
        {
            ItemCode = "2010101000004",
            ItemDescription = "Beginners First Col & Tracing Alphabet Book",
            Quantity = 4,
            Price = 40          
        }
    };
}
```

This returns the following:

```
19 0 2010101000003 1 4/25/2020 12:00:00 AM 20
21 0 2010101000003 1 4/27/2020 12:00:00 AM 20
21 1 2010101000004 4 4/27/2020 12:00:00 AM 40
```

Comment: The list in this case should just return 3 rows. The DocEntrys should be 19, 21, 21. The itemcodes should be 2010101000003, 2010101000003 and 2010101000004. The quantities should be 1, 1, and 4. The docentry is needed to close off open goods receipts.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau This answer is completely true. Differences between Carlo results and what you expected are due to some mismatch in test data of Carol code (GetReceipts and GetInvoices). I test the algorithm by fixing them and the results are exactly what you mentioned above

Comment: Yes, the difference was the test data, not the solution. I decided to incorporate your NB comment to show that the solution works for that expanded scenario. I've accepted the edit that removed that test data to show you the exact data as requested. If you agree please mark this solution as the answer.

Comment: Small issue. There seems to be a problem when the assembly/invoice has a quantity of just 1. What happens is that 2 rows of 1 show up if that grpolist has more than one entry of the same itemcode.

Comment: Okay, fixed. Decrementing the to-be ordered totals in the GetToShipFromReceipt method fixed it for the additional scenario where the invoice is completely fulfilled by the a portion of the receipts.